# Does JRebel work with JBoss Fuse?

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, jrebel

Im working on a large project and the build process is slow to Fuse, so Im looking into hot deployment. Ive had a look at JRebel - but cannot see support for Fuse/Karaf - so am wondering if they would work together? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRebel works with Karaf, really the best thing to do is just try it out. Depending on how you're running your app (in the IDE vs command line) you may need to add the JAVA_OPTS yourself. The IDE plugin can generate them for you.